# AngularJS an Bootstrap tooltip with span

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I have an Angular1.0.7 web application. I´m adding a Twitter Bootstrap 2 tooltip to an span tag, but the tooltip is displayed very narrow. This is not happening with many other tooltips I have in the application.

```
<span style="line-height: 45px" ng-show="controlSkipperType || createBoatPoliciesForm.skipperType.$error.validateSkipperType" class="text-error" ng-switch="skipperTypeError">                  
    <span ng-switch-when="OPTIONAL_ERROR" style="position: relative; top: -15px; margin-left: 10px" class="pull-left">{{'SKIPPER_TYPE_OPTIONAL_ERROR' | translate}}.</span>
    <span ng-switch="skipperTypeError" style="position: relative; top: -15px; margin-left: 10px">
    <i ng-switch-when="OPTIONAL_ERROR" class="fa-icon-question-sign" tooltip="Text to show in the tooltip"></i>
```

See the picture:
[image]

Comment: just change `class` for `tooltip` you can change the width there. Use child properties to change for particular tootip

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
div > div .popover-content {
   min-width: 620px !important;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I don´t understand it. Could you please do it with my own code above?